# Trigger click on origin page using element injected by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension which injects a link into the page which upon click triggers a click on two links visible within the page. It works when I run the code from the console, but due to Chromes Isolated World handling of extensions, the click event fails to fire on the origin page links. Is there a way around this?

Code:

```
function foo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.myElement').children('a.first-link').click();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.myElement').children('a.second-link').click();
}


$(document).on('mouseover', 'div.content', function() {
    if($(this).find('ul').children('li').length === 0) {
        var li = $('<li class="foo"></li>');
        var a = $('<a href="#">Action</a>');
        a.on('click', foo);
        li.append(a);
        $(this).find('ul').children('.myElement').after(li);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you give enough permissions? is your script actually running?

Comment: To my knowledge - yes, are you implying that one of the permissions would allow for this to work? Which one might I need?

Comment: Actually - I didn't declare any permissions, this is the extent of my manifest: 

`{
 "name": "my extension",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "my description",
 "content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["http://mysite.com/*", "https://mysite.com/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "js/switcher.js"]
   }
 ]
}`